# Single word request for "finished reading" or "completed reading"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a single word that means "finished reading" or "completed reading"?

I want to use it in a sentence like this:

> I *finished reading* this book yesterday.

But while doing so, replace the two words "finished reading" with a single word:

> I ___________ this book yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @Valcor's answer, one could add **completed** to **finished** as a possible answer. Replacing **finished** by **completed** in Valcor's answer, one has:

> In English, the sentence "I **completed** this book yesterday" is understood as reading, unless the context is specifically about authorship.

So you could replace *finished reading* or *completed reading* with either **finished** or **completed** with little chance of confusion:

> I **finished** this book yesterday.
>
> I **completed** this book yesterday.

Answer (score 5):

You can either finish writing a book or reading a book, and it's almost always the latter.

In English, the sentence "I finished this book yesterday" is understood as reading, unless the context is specifically about authorship.